# Python - IBM Watson Language Translator v3 - uploading content of a file and downloading the result

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, ibm-watson

I'm trying to use the Python SDK for IBM Watson Language Translator v3, testing the beta functionality of translating actual documents. Below is my code:-

```
from ibm_watson import LanguageTranslatorV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

API = "1234567890abcdefg"
GATEWAY = 'https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api'

document_list = []

"""The below authenticates to the IBM Watson service and initiates an instance"""
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(API)
language_translator = LanguageTranslatorV3(
    version='2018-05-01',
    authenticator=authenticator
)

language_translator.set_service_url(GATEWAY)

submission = language_translator.translate_document(file="myfile.txt", filename="myfile.txt", file_content_type='text/plain', model_id=None, source='en', target='es', document_id=None)
document_list.append(submission.result['document_id'])

while len(document_list) > 0:
    for document in document_list:
        document_status = language_translator.get_document_status(document)
        if document_status.result['status'] == "available":
            translated_document = language_translator.get_translated_document(document)
            document_list.remove(document)
            language_translator.delete_document(document)
```

A few questions on this:-

1. When I check the content of 'translated_document', it doesn't actually contain any content. It contains the headers and the HTTP status of the response but no actually translated content
2. I decided to use CURL to download my uploaded document and instead of the actual content of the .txt file being uploaded for translation, when downloading the translated file via CURL, it appears that the content is the actual file name (myfile.txt) that is being submitted for translation as opposed to the content of the file.

Researching this and looking at the actual IBM Watson Github respository, it appears that I may have to read the content of 'myfile.txt' to a variable and then pass this variable as 'file={my_variable}' when submitting the translation but doesn't this defeat the object of being able to submit the actual documents for translation? How is this different to the conventional service offered?

Can anybody advise me as to what I'm doing wrong? I've tried multiple approaches (writing the value of 'translated_content' to a file) for example but I just don't seem to be able to grab the translated content nor can I seem to actually upload the content of the file to the service, instead I simply appear to submit the filename.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The `file` parameter of `translate_document` is supposed to be the actual content to be translated.  I realize that's not clear from the documentation, but that's how the service works.  So try passing the actual content you want translated in the `file` parameter.